# Page not found (404) with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to incorporate django-allauth on my project. So far so good with the installation, but when I try to access the 'accounts' page, I get a "page not found 404" error.

Here's the output:

```
Using the URLconf defined in Mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^$ [name='home']
    ^contact$ [name='contact']
    ^about [name='about']
    ^login/$ [name='login']
    ^logout$ [name='logout']
    ^admin/
    ^accounts/
The current URL, accounts, didn't match any of these.
```

Here's the Mysite.urls file:

```
"""
Definition of urls for Mysite.
"""

from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app.forms import BootstrapAuthenticationForm

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', 'app.views.contact', name='contact'),

    # SNIP #

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Allauth
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
)
```

All the stuff I've done is done after [this installation documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). I've basically copy-pasted all the stuff to settings.py.

What could be the cause here? I don't get any errors when running `manage.py syncdb` or when launching the server.

Comment: I know Django is finicky about slashes, so just to be sure: did you try `accounts/` (i.e. with a slash appended)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

allauth doesn't have an "index" page (`/accounts/`). Instead, you can access pages like:

```
/accounts/signup/
/accounts/login/
```

If you set `DEBUG = True` in settings.py, you will be able to see all available pages under `/accounts/`, like:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I still couldn't access the signup or login pages, but that was because I was already logged in using the Django auth. Once I logged out, it worked. :)